# Errors when executing a hardening apache script

Tags: bash

**Code**:

```
grep -i '^User' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
if User apache
then
echo -e "User apache exists" >> /tmp/hard_test
#
fi
grep -i '^Group' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
if Group apache
then
echo -e "Group apache exists" >> /tmp/hard_test
fi
```

**Errors**:

command User not found, command Group not found

Comment: I got the following errors: command User not found, command Group not found

Comment: Check your code. The lines `if User apache` and  `if Group apache` need to be changed appropriately to check the conditions.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You will get a much better response here if you take a little care with your question.  You have made no attempt to format it so we can read it, and you haven't even asked a question.  Check out the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) guide, and experiment with the editor tools when writing/editing your questions.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
if grep -qi '^User.apache' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf; then 
    echo -e "User apache exists" >> /tmp/hard_test
fi

if grep -qi '^Group.apache' /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf; then 
    echo -e "Group apache exists" >> /tmp/hard_test
fi
```